# How to merge two DataFrame columns and apply pandas.to_datetime to it?

Tags: python, pandas

I''m learning to use pandas, to use it for some data analysis. The data is supplied as a csv file, with several columns, of which i only need to use 4  (date, time, o, c). I'll like to create a new DataFrame, which uses as index a DateTime64 number, this number is creating by merging the first two columns, applying pd.to_datetime on the merged string.

My loader code works fine:

```
st = pd.read_csv("C:/Data/stockname.txt", names=["date","time","o","h","l","c","vol"])
```

The challenge is converting the loaded DataFrame into a new one, with the right format. The below works but is very slow. Moreover, it just makes one column with the new datetime64 format, and doesnt make it the index.

My code

```
st_new = pd.concat([pd.to_datetime(st.date + " " + st.time), (st.o + st.c) / 2, st.vol], 
     axis = 1, ignore_index=True)
```

What would be a more pythonic way to merge two columns, and apply a function into the result?
How to make the new column to be the index of the DataFrame?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do everythin in the `read_csv` function:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv',
            parse_dates={'timestamp': ['date','time']},
            index_col='timestamp',
            usecols=['date', 'time', 'o', 'c'])
```

`parse_dates` tells the `read_csv` function to combine the `date` and `time` column into one `timestamp` column and parse it as a timestamp. (pandas is smart enough to know how to parse a date in various formats)

`index_col` sets the `timestamp` column to be the index.

`usecols` tells the `read_csv` function to select only the subset of the columns.

Comment: I believe ``usecols should be ['date','time','o','h','l','c','vol]``?

Comment: He said: _of which i only need to use 4 (date, time, o, c)_ so I selected just them.

Comment: +1 I didn't know about that `parse_dates` awesomeness. @Jeff is that new?

Comment: @ViktorKerkez thanks, this makes lots of sense. Still, one detail, the challenge of applying a function and combining columns into a new d

Comment: Not sure what you want, the question is not finished?

Comment: Actually, it is, as it was posed. The solution is great. The solution, though, may not allow  to add two columns as in 

`(st.o + st.c) / 2`

as the loading happens directly into the DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

As far as loading the data in, I think you've got it. To set the index do this:

```
st_new = pd.concat([(st.o + st.c) / 2, st.vol], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
st_new.set_index(pd.to_datetime(st.date + " " + st.time), drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Here's the [API documentation for `set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html?highlight=set_index#pandas.DataFrame.set_index).