# How to merge 2 columns in 1 within same dataframe (Python, Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm following tutorial of Wes McKinney on using pandas/python for trading backtesting (http://youtu.be/6h0IVlp_1l8).
After pd.read_csv(...) he's using 'dt' (datetime) column as index of dataframe.

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('dt'))
```

However, my data has 2 separate columns, 'Date[G]' and 'Time[G]' and the data inside is something like 04-JAN-2013,00:00:00.000 (comma-separated).

How do i modify that line of code in order to do the same? I.e. merge two columns within one data frame, and then delete it. Or is there a way to do that during read_csv itself?

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: I honestly looked for answer before asking, however only after I've posted I saw similar question in 'Related' section, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18115222/how-to-merge-two-dataframe-columns-and-apply-pandas-to-datetime-to-it?rq=1

So in my case the answer seems to be:

    df = pd.read_csv('%s%s.csv' % (stock, '_1min'), 
                    parse_dates={'timestamp': ['Date[G]','Time[G]']},
                    index_col='timestamp',
                    usecols=['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Last', 'Date[G]', 'Time[G]'])'

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to concat two columns using apply() and then use to_datetime().
To remove columns from dataframe use drop() or just select columns you need:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df.apply(lambda x: x['Date[G]'] + ' ' + x['Time[G]'], 1))


df = df.drop(['Date[G]', 'Time[G]'], 1)
# ..or
# df = df[['dt', ...]]

df.set_index('dt', inplace = True)
```